# Probability of observation if event is subset of two possible events

Tags: probability

given that I have three different States A, B, C each having a probability of (A 38%, B 4%, C 58%) occurence.

Each event has a subset: A->X1, B->X2 and C->X1,X2 occur together.

How can I calculate which X is more likely to occur? Can I just add or multiply the probabilities of A and C to get the probabilty of X1? 
Thanks in Advance

Comment: The first line makes it sound like $A$, $B$, and $C$ are mutually exclusive, especially since the percentages add up to 100%. And the second line seems to be saying that $X_1 ⊆ A$, $X_2 ⊆ B$, and $X_1 ∩ X_2 ⊆ C$. Since $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, so are $X_1$ and $X_2$, so $X_1 ∩ X_2$ is empty. Do I understand you correctly?

Comment: Sorry I didn't specify it clearly. I just realized subset might have been the wrong term, it is more like a Symbol or an Observation. So here is a little more background: A,B and C are States that I predict with a probability and they are as you said mutually exclusive. However in each state I can observe a Symbol: In A I can only observe X1, in State B I can only observe X2, but in State B I can observe X1 and X2. So I think the probability of seeing X1 should somehow be combined of the probability of seeing it in A and seeing it in C. Is that the case or am I making a wrong assumption?

Comment: Your language is still informal. Try [describing your real problem, with context](http://arfer.net/w/statqgl). Then, I or some other statistician can figure out what the right formalization is.